# Jquery manual slide show

Tags: jquery, slideshow, delay

I am writing a slideshow script manually instead of using the other ready made packages. The reason is that in my slide show, some slides might be images, some might be videos or some might be interactive. So I am tackling this myself.

I am having a problem with the timing. I am writing loop scritps to query a database to get all of the slides and then to loop through and show each one:

```
while(jslideNumber <= numberOfSlides){
 $('.slide'+jslideNumber).delay(jslideNumber*8000).fadeIn(1000).delay(5000).fadeOut(1000).delay(2000);
 jslideNumber++;
 console.log("jslideNumber: "+jslideNumber)
}
```

the problem is that in this example there are 5 slides. The script above shows all 5 at the same time, delays 5 seconds and then hides them all at the same time. What am I doing wrong? Like any other slide show, this should show one slide for a time, wait, hide, then show the next slide.

OK: EDIT thanks to a gentleman below, I do have a script that shows individual images for a specific time, however the console log is listing all 6 jslideNumbers before the first slide even shows. That means that all 6 have been loaded and the script has not even started yet. With that, what if there are 300 slides?

What I prefer to have is

```
Show Slide 1
wait 30 10sec
log slide 1

show Slide 2
wait 30sec
log slide 2

...
```

Instead what the script above really does is:

```
Log Slide1
Log Slide2
Log Slide3 ...

Show Slide 1
Hide SLide 1
Show Slide 2
Hide Slide 2 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are many ways you could do it, but right now, you are telling all the slides to do the exact same thing.  The closest thing to what you have I can think of that might work is:

```
while(jslideNumber <= numberOfSlides){
   $('.slide'+jslideNumber).delay(jslideNumber*8000).fadeIn(1000).delay(5000).fadeOut(1000).delay(2000);
   jslideNumber++;
   console.log("jslideNumber: "+jslideNumber)
}
```

That assumes jslideNumber starts with 0 (as any good programmer would do).

There are really BETTER ways, so as using setTimeout or setInterval, but maybe you can understand this best.

Comment: I did try using setTimeout and the results were the same. Are you sure that the delay *8000 makes sense above?

Comment: Not sure this is quite right. It does show individual images for a specified time as it should, however the console log is writing all of the jslideNumber before the first image even appears. That means that in the case of a video slide for example, then it would already start playing before it would show. What I am trying to do is edited above